# PHP openssl_ Decrypting data

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I have a situation where I am being sent some encrypted data from a vendor which I need to decode.

The data has been encrypted with my public key and signed with the vendors private before being base64encoded and transmitted to my server as a POST variable. - I have no control over this. For more into the vendor is running a .net system and our system is a linux distro.

I am having lots of difficulties in getting this data decrypted so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am told that I can "simply" decode after base64decoding the data by using my private key and the vendors public key.

The code that I have currently looks like this

```
$data = base64_decode($_POST['encryptedData']);

$public     = openssl_get_publickey('/path/vendors/public/key.cer');
$private    = openssl_get_privatekey('/path/to/my/private/key.key');

$env_key = $public;

if (openssl_open($data, $open, $env_key, $private)) {
    echo "here is the opened data: ", $open;
} else {
    echo "failed to open data";
}
```

I am familiar with PHP but never used the openssl library before

Its actually coming from a SSO type application however I do not believe that I need to implement phpSAMP etc as all I need to do is decrypt the data that is being sent to me (Assertion)

I am also a little unsure if the public and private key that I am using are 100% correct. when I look at my public key its more like how the private key looks rather than the hex format.

my Private key looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
FRt6SFwIBAAKCAQEAn2D2XXXXXsfdsSDFSDF534MR/5Efsfs4OWNTtc34yYgO1cu
2GYh07MOZnrz5VsDJg8iacB1B3FAA0qrNLFuU8BEnLYDk36zyDurJwkBfCFc1MHq
lIfhUT9/bT/5naQGQ29dJZuXsfdsSDFSDF534MR/5Efsfshpf0qWArj5qBJduVc+
....truncated
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the public key looks like:

```
0ad2 ca15 c2d3 5e82 b9a4 ae81 6898 b9bf
cef6 a464 e382 b897 1755 956c 79df fe15
3a44 8c75 47bf 8a54 375f d611 c4ec 551c
...... More Data
724e 536d c437 0383 66ca c998 a357 4e1a
f7ad bdf0 cc13 2152 354b f8
```

I have a good look around the internet and cannot find any working examples for this specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NB: there is some cypher info and x509 cert info in the response. is it possible that I should be using this in the openssl_open() function rather than calling the text strings from the vendor certs stored on my server?

Comment: Note that you may want to remove the previous question about this (I presume it is the same problem). That one does not contain enough data to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is encrypted, and then signed, and assuming CMS format (the former PKCS#7) then I guess you need to verify it first, retrieve the content (check the function) and then decrypt that. More information (seems to be) [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-verify.php).

Comment: Thanks owlstead. I'll check this out tomorrow. You are quite correct about this previous post. - I've removed it not (I think).

Comment: @BunnyHuggan It sure seems gone to me :)

Comment: Hi, Yes and no, It turns out the the route I was taking is correct for encryption and decryption of data using private / public keys, but the application that I was working with being in .net and myself working in PHP (x domain), the 2 systems although should, were not playing nicely together. so the solution has been to build a windows box to handle this solution which is now working perfectly!! maybe for completion if anyone has any knowledge of how to achieve this from .net -> PHP environments they can post it here? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This doesn't help solve the issue here on StackOverflow. Asking additional questions here is not nice. Please delete the question if you think it cannot be solved or post a solution.